# importance of exec command while reading from file

Tags: shell

I found following piece of code written as a shell script to read from a file line by line.

```
BAKIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"$FILE"
while read -r line
do
 # use $line variable to process line in processLine() function
 processLine $line
done
exec 0<&3

# restore $IFS which was used to determine what the field separators are
IFS=$BAKIFS
```

I am unable to understand the need of three exec commands mentioned. Can someone elaborate it for me. Also is the $ifs variable reset after every single read from a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`exec` on its own (with no arguments) will not start a new process but can be used to manipulate file handles in the current process.

What these lines are doing is:

- temporarily save the current standard input (file handle 0) into file handle 3.
- modify standard input to read from `$FILE`.
- do the reading.
- set standard input back to the original value (from file handle 3).

`IFS` is not reset after every `read`, it stays as `"\n\b"` for the duration of the `while` loop and is reset to its original value with `IFS=$BAKIFS` (saved earlier).

---

In detail:

```
BAKIFS=$IFS                    # save current input field separator
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")         #   and change it.

exec 3<&0                      # save current stdin
exec 0<"$FILE"                 #   and change it to read from file.

while read -r line ; do        # read every line from stdin (currently file).
  processLine $line            #   and process it.
done

exec 0<&3                      # restore previous stdin.
IFS=$BAKIFS                    #   and IFS.
```

Comment: thanks so much pax....suppose i run this script on a server in background.Then during the duration of while loop the standard input would be set to 3. Does that mean that i wont be able to use standard input to read for any other program for that duration?? any ideas so as to remove this dependency?

Comment: That file handle belongs to the _process_, it's not a system-wide resource. For example, every process gets its own standard input (file handle 0) without conflicting with other processes. So, if you're talking about programs running separate from that one, no. Of course, within the process, you couldn't (for example) have another line reading from the "real" stdin within the while loop since it would get the next line from the file instead).

Answer (score 0):

The code shown is equivalent to:

```
while read -r line
do
    ...
done < "$FILE"
```

By the way, you can do this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

in shells such as Bash that support it.